# ansible 1.8 does not resolve item.key in set_facts

Tags: ansible

So i have the below section in my playbook:

```
- name: Loop hash
  set_fact:
   "{{ item.key }}":
      instance_id: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
      instance_az: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}"
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars }}"
  when: (item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id is defined) and
        (item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone is defined)
```

when I check the output it is not resolving item.key

```
'item.key': {'instance_id': u'i-abc12345678', 'instance_az': u'ap-southeast-2b'}
```

any ideas on whats going on?

edit:

error for suggested solution:

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /apps/co-playbooks/common/tasks/elb_check_instances.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 40, column 18

   { "{{ item.key }}":
      instance_id: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
                 ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
```

tried different syntax:

```
- name: Loop hash
  set_fact:
   { "{{ item.key }}":
      { instance_id: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}",
        instance_az: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}" }}

  with_dict: "{{ hostvars }}"
  when: (item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id is defined) and
        (item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone is defined)
```

still does not resolve item.key

```
'{# item.key #}': {'instance_id': u'i-abc1234567', 'instance_az': u'ap-southeast-2b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one pair of `{ }` outside the set_fact task.

```
- name: Loop hash
  set_fact:
   { "{{ item.key }}":
      instance_id: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
      instance_az: "{{ item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}" }
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars }}"
  when: (item.value.ansible_ec2_instance_id is defined) and
        (item.value.ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone is defined)
```

Comment: Hi BMW, thanks for the reply. It does not seem to like the new format and gives me a syntax error. I have updated my original question as this comment section does not display the syntax well.